# Paint a rectangle over an image and save the new image in C# Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, heatmap

I want to create some sort of heatmap, i have a template image to use, so, i want to draw/paint a full circle, rectangle over the imagen in a point that i already know.

Like for example from the x:200, y:200 to x:250, y :250, take the base image, paint a full rectangle of some color over it, and save the new image.

What will be the easiest way to do it, or the best approach to solve the problem. I'm using a webform with C# on Visual Studio

Thanks

Comment: I'd do a rest service that takes the image, creates a graphics object from it, draw rectangle.  Return the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to paint a rectangle is pretty trivial.  Obtain your image object using whatever makes the most sense, get a graphics object from that, and draw.

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile("yourfile.jpg"))
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
{
    g.FillRectangle(br, 200, 200, 50, 50);
    img.Save("YourNewFile.jpg");
}
```